# Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, resources, aspose

I am working on a .NET Solution with many project. One of these projects is called `DAL.EF`. In Visual Studio 2012, I right click the project and go to its properties.

Once there I click on the Resources tab (on the left) and add my two Aspose Library license keys.

[image: resource]

In my code, I want to gain access to the license keys, so I do:

```
switch (license)
{
    case LicenseType.AsposePdfKit:
        licenseContent = Properties.Resources.AsposePdfKit;
        break;
    case LicenseType.AsposeWords:
        licenseContent = Properties.Resources.AsposeWords;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Wrong License type passed into Aspose!");
        break;
}
```

But on both lines where I am trying to access the `Properties` I get the following error:

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your Resources.Designers.cs. and try write full namespace

Comment: Have you saved after adding properties in `Resources tab`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! All I had to do was change the Access Modifier on the Resources from `Internal` to `Public`.

[image]